# MVC 4 Entity Framework Cannot Connect to Dynamically Created Database from IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

After I hosted my apps in my localhost IIS, suddenly the system gives me error:

> Cannot open database "AlvinCMS" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

The database AlvinCMS is created at runtime. The system has no problem when in debug mode.

Here is my global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //Check And Init Database
        Alvin_CMS.App_Start.DatabaseConfig.Initialize();
        ......
```

This is my initialization:

```
public static void Initialize()
{
    Alvin_CMS.Models.AlvinCMSMigrationDBContext migrationDB = new Models.AlvinCMSMigrationDBContext();
    try
    {
        if (!migrationDB.Database.Exists())
        {
            migrationDB.Database.Initialize(false); //THIS CREATES DATABASE
            AlvinCMSExtension.Models.AccountDBContext accountDB = new AlvinCMSExtension.Models.AccountDBContext();
            accountDB.Database.Initialize(false);
            SetDefaultValue(migrationDB);
        }
        migrationDB.Database.Initialize(false);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        migrationDB.Database.Delete();
        AlvinCMSExtension.Helper.Log(e);
    }
}
```

Here is my context:

```
public AlvinCMSMigrationDBContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<AlvinCMSMigrationDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AlvinCMSMigrationDBContext>());
}
```

I set the apps pool to use `LocalSystem` and I have `IntegratedSecurity=true` in my connection string. How can I fix this error?

**NOTE: If I run this on visual studio development server, it runs fine with no error. Also if I use localDB and run it on IIS Express, it runs fine too. The Problem only exist if I use IIS, even when I debug the program from Visual Studio Local IIS Web Server, then the error is produced**

---

### UPDATE

After 4 hours of debugging, finally I know what is wrong. The error exists because the database is not exist. I have another database error that causes the code to enter Exception, so the database is not being created.

The problematic database has this connection string:

`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\Alvin CMS Project\Alvin CMS\Alvin CMS\App_Data\db\backup\AlvinCMS_Default.mdf";Initial Catalog=AlvinCMS_Default;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

When hosted on IIS, the program cannot attach the database. It causes this error:

> {"Unable to open the physical file \"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\Alvin CMS Project\Alvin CMS\Alvin CMS\App_Data\db\backup\AlvinCMS_Default.mdf\". Operating system error 5: \"5(Access is denied.)\".\r\nCannot attach the file 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\Alvin CMS Project\Alvin CMS\Alvin CMS\App_Data\db\backup\AlvinCMS_Default.mdf' as database 'AlvinCMS_Default'."}

But when I use visual development server, it works fine. So the new question arises, how can I safely attach the database without causing errors when hosted on IIS server?

Comment: Allow NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM to server Role as sysadmin.

Comment: What authentication is enabled in IIS ?

Comment: I did change the NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM to sysadmin, but still the error is not fixed. The authentication for IIS is `Local System` this will use the NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM to access the database am I right?

Comment: @AlvinStefanus Add your connection string in the question.

Comment: I have updated the question, apparently there is another database that causes the code to enter the Exception, that is why the AlvinCMS database cannot be accessed, because it does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like stated above the updated question, actually there was never be any problem with the database connection. What actually happened was there is an access denied when I tried to access another database, which made the code entered the Exception and never touch the database creation. That is why I cannot login to access the database, because the database was never created.

Then I need to fix the another database which caused the fault. The problem was I cannot attach the database. The access was keep being denied. After I have done some research **I found that I was using LocalDB before I use SQLEXPRESS. I deleted the database from LocalDB, but apparently the localDB is still referencing the database, that is why I got my access denied because the database was still being used by LocalDB. So what I did was to run:

`sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0` from cmd (you can run it from command line in visual studio as well).

Then after that, I can finally attached my database with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with following things:

1. Add `Integrated Security=SSPI` in your `Web.Config`
2. Allow `NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM` to server Role as sysadmin.

   Goto security > Logins > Select `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`

[image]

Give it the necessary permissions it needs for your app.

[image]

Comment: I already assigned the NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM as sysadmin. I tried to change IntegratedSecurity=SSPI. But the error is still the same `Cannot open database "AlvinCMS" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.`